# regular expression issue in TCL for checking

Tags: tcl

In TCL, I have declared an array sstr with some patterns and  I would like to match that patterns with the cryplist. If I found that match, I am displaying with array key and the matched list member. But the below program is not working. Hope I did some mistake in the declaration of regular expression.

```
#!/bin/tclsh
set cryplist [list "$:adzctg-cm20decadt/sr" "$:yyzpty-cm23febadt/sr" "dc*aed1740.0*gbp" "dc*ars1*usd" "dc*gbp10.00*/r" "d|t|lbb/den" "d|t|ordphx"]
array set sstr {
    z "dc*[a-z]{3}*"
    dl "d\$*[0-9]"
    fd "\$:[a-z]{6}"
    md "d|t|[a-z]{3}\/[a-z]{3}"
    ms "d|t|[a-z]{6}"
}

foreach i $cryplist {
    puts "------------- $i --------------"
    foreach {n str} [array get sstr] {
        puts "$n -> $str"
        if { [regexp {$str} $i ] } {
            puts "============= $n -> $i ================"
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using `regexp {$str} $i`, which makes the regular expression be the *literal* `$str` and not the contents of the `str` variable. Change to `regexp -- $str $i` and it should work; the `--` says “no further options” (just for safety) and the unquoted `$str` reads from the variable for that argument (what you want).

Comment: Still not getting the right answer..  ------------- $:adzctg-cm20decadt/sr --------------
ms -> d|t|[a-z]{6}
============= ms -> $:adzctg-cm20decadt/sr ================
------------- $:yyzpty-cm23febadt/sr --------------
ms -> d|t|[a-z]{6}
============= ms -> $:yyzpty-cm23febadt/sr ================
------------- dc*aed1740.0*gbp --------------
ms -> d|t|[a-z]{6}

Comment: @Tamilan Why isn't that the right answer? Can you point out the part that you didn't expect, and explain why you didn't expect it?